# Array of Arrays to Dictonary JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I Have an array of arrays and would like to return a dictionary like so.

```
function retFunc(array) {
var dict ={};
for(var i=0; i<=array.length-1;i++){
dict={[array[i][0]] : array[i][1]}
}
return dict
}  

retFunc([['a','b'],'['c','d']])

output
{ c : 'd'}
```

the return dict only returns the last key/value pair.  I would like to return all key/value pairs but doing something like dict += {[array[i][0]] : array[i][1]} doesn't work.

Comment: You seem to have a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing

```
dict={[array[i][0]] : array[i][1]}
```

That means you assign a new object to variable dict. Not appending!
If you want to append to your dict object. Write this:

```
dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple with [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), and parameter destructuring:

```js
function retFunc(arr) {
  return Object.assign({}, ...arr.map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v})));
}

console.log(retFunc([['a','b'],['c','d']]));
```

Answer (score 0):

you would have to do

```js
function retFunc(array) {
var dict ={};
for(var i=0; i<=array.length-1;i++){
dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
}
return dict
}  

console.log(retFunc([['a','b'],['c','d']]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead use `dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];` to map all key values.

```js
function retFunc(array) {
var dict ={};
for(var i=0; i<=array.length-1;i++){
dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
}
return dict
}  

var x = retFunc([['a','b'],['c','d']]);

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use assignment as `dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1]` to add a `key:value` pair to your dict [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Remove the typo as well from the array.

```js
function retFunc(array) {
  var dict = {};
  for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
    dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1]
  }
  return dict
}

console.log(retFunc([
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd']
]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this with `object` key = value assignment,

```js
function retFunc(array) {
  var dict = {};
  for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
    dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
  }
  return dict;
}

console.log(retFunc([
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['c', 'd']
]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a direct assignment to the wanted key.

```
dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
```

```js
function retFunc(array) {
    var dict = {};
    for (var i = 0; i <= array.length - 1; i++) {
          dict[array[i][0]] = array[i][1];
    }
    return dict;
}

console.log(retFunc([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]));
```

A more functional approach could include

- [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for collecting parts of an object,
- [spread syntax `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) for taking an array as parameters
- [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) for getting a new array,
- [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for  having the values of an object instead of using an array, and
- [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) to use a variable as key.

```js
function retFunc(array) {
    return Object.assign(...array.map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v })));
}

console.log(retFunc([['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd']]));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect candidate for the `Array.reduce` function. Below is a commented example that shows how `Array.reduce` works for your example. You can also find documentation at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=a)

```js
const input = [
  ['a', 'b'],
  ['d', 'd'],
  ['e', 'f'],
];

// adds key/value from `arr` to dict.
function arrayToDict(dict, arr){
  dict = dict || {};
  // take an array of two items and turn it into a key value pair.
  let [key, value] = arr;
  // if you don't like es6 syntax, then this is equivalent
  /*
  var key   = arr[0];
  var value = arr[1];
  */
  
  dict[key] = value;
  return dict;
}

// this function can be used to add any one of our pairs to a dictionary

console.log('Example1: ', arrayToDict({}, ['a', 'b']));

// now we can use the Array Reduce function to add each pair to the dictionary.

let output = input.reduce(arrayToDict, {});
console.log('Output:', output);
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Object.fromEntries() method transforms a list of key-value pairs into an object.
> [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries)

> Object.fromEntries(iterable);

```
var array = [
   ['a','b'],
   ['c','d']
];
var dict = Object.fromEntries(array);
console.log(dict);

// {a: "b", c: "d"}
```